# How do I rewrite a function as a lambda function using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have a function:

```
def function(x):
    return x > 0
data['number'] = data['arr_nums'].apply(function)
```

How do I rewrite this as a lambda function by using pandas? Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: Why are we moving this to a lambda? Some vectorized operation would be much faster `data['number'] = data['arr_nums'] > 0` and if the goal is readability the faster operation wins there too.

Answer (score -1):

```
e = lambda a: a>0
print(e(13))e = lambda a: a>0
print(e(13))
```

you can use like this. If you found it useful, I would appreciate it if you support it :)

Answer (score -1):

Very simple solution:

```
function = lambda a : a > 0
data['number'] = function(data['arr_nums'])
```